# PHPExcel не видит ячейку

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Беру значения из колонки G (колонка 6), запихиваю всё в массив

```
$countRow = $this->sheet->getHighestRow();
$arCompany = [];
$column = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($this->settings['winner']) - 1;
for ($i = 3; $i <= $countRow; $i++) {
    $arCompany[$i] = $this->sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $i)->getValue();
}
```

Проблема: до 25 строки всё нормально, затем колонка прыгает почему-то на H, хотя по коду она всё еще G.

Пробую ради интереса найти нужную ячейку в 25 строке. Формат таблицы:

-------F-------------G-------------H--------

--Сумма-----Компания----Еmail------

```
$test = $this->sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, 25)->getValue();
$test2 = $this->sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, 25)->getValue();
var_dump($test); echo '<br>'; var_dump($test2);
```

Должно вывести:

Сумма---Компания

По факту:

Сумма---Email

Не видит при запросе данную ячейку, только соседние.
В итоге оказалось, что почему-то ячейка съезжает на колонку B, а она в свою очередь уезжает в конец.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В шапке колонок стояли фильтры. При удалении шапки всё заработало, мешали фильтры как оказалось.